# How do I improve broswer caching

Tags: web

I added the following code to my .htaccess file to leverage browser caching for my website:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

In GTMETRIX it showed that the problem of the browser caching improved a little bit - it went from 0 to 56 in the results - it's in the pic below. But there are still some things that are causing the site to load slowly, should I add some specific code to it or should I use a different one? Or is there a way to resolve the specific issues that are left?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7gUm.png)